# I want to remove double quotes from JSON.stringify object for pass it to amchart

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to remove double quotes from JSON.stringify object for pass it to amchart

```
 var data = JSON.stringify(ChartData);
```

this line gives me the result given below..

```
"[{"USD":"Prod 1","FY 2016":2256},{"USD":"Prod 2","FY 2016":510},{"USD":"Prod 3","FY 2016":503}]"
```

I want to remove begin and last double quotes from the result so that i can pass it to dataprovider of amchart.

Please go through the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please read through the [help] and especially [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - in this case just don't stringify it or use JSON.parse before using a previously stringified object

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can use:

```
dati=dati.split('"').join('');
```

Comment: I want to remove begin and last double quotes from the result actually. In screen shot i have indicate with arrow sign.

Answer (score 0):

> why you stringfy your data?using this you can direct get your json result.

```
 var jsonResult = Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i am fetching the record from web api.And there is multiple list in that.